# i want my application to go to background and resume on call end 

Tags: iphone, call

I am working on creating a call application, i am making a call from my app through

```
NSURL *targetUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:targetUrl];
```

but by these ,my application quits , i want my application to go to background and resume on call end ...please help...

regards

Comment: For which iOS device you are developing... 3.x or 4.x ?

Comment: 4.x an application PhoneTap in app stores does it, even call recording is it possible ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Using telprompt url instead of tel solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", ph]];
        [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];